# apache redirect in https from none www to www domain

Tags: apache, redirect, http-host

Edit:
`Redirect permanent "/" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/"` actually doesn't work in the first redirect. It appeared to work because my CDN automatically redirected http to https:, not because of my settings. Sorry for the confusion.

---

I am trying to write Apache httpd config file to redirect all http traffic to https, and also need to redirect none www domain to www.

for example
`http://example.com   http://www.example.com   https://example.com`   
should all be redirected to
`https://www.example.com`

Here is what I did:

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:80>  
  ServerName example.com  
  ServerAlias www.example.com  

  Redirect permanent "/" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This part works. All http is redirect to https. Note, the %{HTTP_HOST} is resolved and replaced.
Now I need to redirect none www to www

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} !~ /www/">
     Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/"
  </If>

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `https://example.com` it redirects but this time it is redirected to
`https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/` instead of `https://www.example.com/`.

Now if I use
`Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.example.com/"`
then `https://example.com` will be redirected to `https://www.example.com`

So it appears that the %{HTTP_HOST} was not replaced in the second VirtualHost block.

How to make it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a rewrite rule

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://example.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
```